# Как сохранить/восстановить раздел с Windows Vista из под Ubuntu?

Tags: vista, ubuntu

Нужен простой подход, по возможности использующий стандартную или с минимальными дополнениями поставку Ubuntu.

Comment: Не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Клонировать раздел Vista можно с помощью ntfsclone, а сжать полученный образ можно с помощью lzma или xz.

Сохранение раздела /dev/sda1 в файл /media/Данные/backup.xz.

```
sudo ntfsclone -o - -s /dev/sda1 | xz -z -c - > /media/Данные/backup.xz
```

Восстановление раздела /dev/sda1 из файла /media/Данные/backup.xz.

```
sudo xz -d -c /media/Данные/backup.xz | ntfsclone -O /dev/sda1 -r -
```

Comment: Удобный способ. Но нужно иметь в виду, что сохранение образа небыстрое. У меня для раздела размером 40 Гб, занятого наполовину, сохранение заняло 9 часов, а восстановление - 20 минут.

Answer (score -1):

Если есть графическая оболочка, лучше используйте gparted. Меньше шансов что-то сломать.