# Образ винта с ext3

Tags: windows, ext3, linux

Проблем следующая:

Есть win7 (уж так вышло), есть винт с разделами в ext3, винда их не видит и мне это по сути не нужно. Нужно сделать полную копию винта! Сначала на комп с win7, а потом из этого файла слить на чистый винт без разделов вообще.

Вопрос: Как?

Comment: symantec ghost на Piratebay есть. можете поискать файл называется ghost32.exe его можно загрузить из любого лайв-дистриба винды, заранее добавив туда конечно. У меня например через WinPE по сети грузится, единственное пока не пробовал на Unix разделах им пользоваться, но в описании на сайте написано что умеет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Norton Ghost и Acronis True Image - удобные программы и если они есть, то ими стоит воспользоваться. Если их нет, можно сделать так:

- создать загрузочную флэшку Ubuntu;
- загрузиться с этой флэшки;
- создать образ всего винчестера (dd) или только нужных разделов (dd, tar):
- восстановиться на новый винчестер из образа.

Если возможно подключить оба винчестера в систему, то быстрее всего копировать с одного на другой. Если же нужен образ и нужно сжимать на лету, то и dd, и tar позволяют это сделать, правда это очень сильно замедлит процесс. Я думаю, что для lzma сжатия время создания образа в 500 Гб может быть больше суток.

О том, как сохранять и восстанавливать разделы, можно посмотреть в [справке](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) Ubuntu. Плюс на этом форуме есть [похожая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/183/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%81-windows-vista-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-ubuntu) тема.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузиться с флэшки проще всего. Есть даже окошки http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ для windows 7. Нужно только сначала записать на флэшку fdisk и tar, тогда нужно будет подключить оба винта, загрузиться с флэшки, просто разбить новый диск fdisk'ом, создать файловые системы, всё смонтировать и слить данные tar'ом. Если диски немного отличаются геометрией, с dd может не получиться.

Есть ещё драйвер ext2/3/4 для винды http://www.ext2fsd.com/, но windows 7 (пока) не поддерживается.

Answer (score 0):

Вашу проблему можно разрешить с помощью утилиты ghost.

Comment: Если Вы про Norton Ghost, то она платная, а триал - глючит и не дает полных возможностей, а ключик не нашел.
Пробую сейчас Acronis True Image, но проблема в том, что у меня на компе 500 гиг, и винт, с которого делаю образ тоже 500гиг, получается, что мне нужно чтобы прога умела сжимать сразу же...

Answer (score 0):

А запустить какой-нибудь linux на виртуальной машине?
VMPlayer бесплатный, образов linux в интернете полно. Скачали, подключили винчестер к образу (VMPlayer это позволяет), загрузили linux, подмонтировали раздел, сделали, что надо.